# A guide to make 32 and 64 bit versions of a library (in Linux)

Tags: g++, x86-64, autotools, configure

I have a 64 bit build environment installed in Ubuntu. Let's say I downloaded a source code of some library and I'd like to build 32 and 64 bit versions of it using single source code.

The library comes with `./configure` script so someone may successfully configure it for 64 bit version like this:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/libtvzombie --with-opengl --with-other-option1
```

... and build and install it to `/opt/libtvzombie` as follows:

```
make
sudo make install
sudo sh -c 'echo /opt/libtvzombie/lib > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/tvzombie.conf'
sudo ldconfig
```

**The questions are:**

1. How can I force the average `./configure` script to compile in 32 bit mode on a 64 bit system? I know I can use `-m32` compile switch with g++, but that's not the way with autotools, because `./configure` recognizes that I’m compiling in a 64 bit environment.
2. Where do I need to install this 32 bit version to? Maybe to `/opt/libzombie32`?
3. Won't there be any name conflicts between 32 bit and 64 bit versions of the library with the same name?

Answer (score 4):

Since configure does not know that the `-m32` flag means "32-bit" (after all, it could mean something completely different with another compiler—it might even be rejected, e.g. on ia64), you should also tell it the host type. The host type may, if the program is so coded, also be used to select certain behavior independent of CC and CFLAGS, --host= should always be specified if the config you want to run as is not the one that is autodetected.

```
./configure --host=i686-linux-gnu CFLAGS="-m32" LDFLAGS="-m32"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to install in /opt/libzombie32, you just need to specify --prefix=/opt/libzombie32 and specify -m32 in CFLAGS.  Personally, I think it is a bad idea to install in a separate directory for each package, and you'd be better off doing something like:

```
$ sudo sh -c 'echo CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -m32" > /opt/lib32/share/config.site'
```

And then configure with --prefix=/opt/lib32.  By specifying CFLAGS in the config.site, any autotooled project configured with --prefix=/opt/lib32 will get -m32 specified in CFLAGS. You may want to specify CXXFLAGS as well, to handle C++.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! As far as I understand the options from `config.site` will be automatically picked up by the `./configure` script, right?

Comment: Didn't you mean `--libdir=/opt/lib32` instead of `--prefix=/opt/lib32`?

Comment: @ezpresso Yes, but only for packages with --prefix=/opt/lib32

Comment: I suppose it would make sense to do --prefix=/opt --libdir=/opt/lib32, but perhaps you want --prefix=/opt/32-bit-builds or something like that.  Don't just use --libdir=/opt/lib32, though, or /usr/local will be the prefix for data files, header files, etc.

Comment: Will headers installed be different for 32 and 64-bit versions of the same library? Is it a bad idea to provide `--includedir=/opt/include` switch to the `./configure'?